# Devise: resetting password does nothing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I'm making a reset password function for my users. The user gets the email with the reset token just fine, and after clicking the link therein they're redirected to the new password form. Once submitting it though nothing happens. The method looks like this:

```
def update
  self.resource = resource_class.reset_password_by_token(resource_params)
  if resource.errors.empty?
    resource.unlock_access! if unlockable?(resource)
    flash_message = resource.active_for_authentication? ? :updated : :updated_not_active
    set_flash_message(:notice, flash_message) if is_flashing_format?
    sign_in(resource_name, resource, :bypass => true)
    redirect_to new_user_session_url, :notice => "Your password has been changed."
  else
    redirect_to new_user_session_url, :flash => { :error => resource.errors.full_messages }
  end
end
```

I'm getting the error flash with no messages in it. Anyone have any ideas? Pretty stuck here. Thanks!

**UPDATE**

Log output:

```
Started PUT "/change.user" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-12-12 11:09:23 +100
Processing by UserPasswordsController#update as 
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"BXUu0J7OVxbKRaRqnI88w/bNuJF5uhaEabnw5GlFj+w=", "user"=>{"reset_password_token"=>"[FILTERED]", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "commit"=>"Change my password"}
User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`reset_password_token` = 'c83cf7b19af0b5eb100d7f1a73eefbeb07ce53980bc1dea14301f7417c4eea32' LIMIT 1
Redirected to http://lvh.me:3000/d/sign_in
Completed 302 Found in 3ms (ActiveRecord: 0.3ms)
```

That's it. No errors, nothing.

**ROUTES**

```
reset_password GET     /reset_password(.:format)          user_passwords#new
new_password GET       /new_password(.:format)            user_passwords#edit
create_password POST   /send_email(.:format)              user_passwords#create
update_password PUT    /change(.:format)                  user_passwords#update
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could *not* figure out what was going on there so I wrote my own method. It works, and maybe it'll help someone else.

```
def update
  @user = User.where(:reset_password_token => params[:user][:reset_password_token]).first
  @user.password = params[:user][:password]
  @user.password_confirmation = params[:user][:password_confirmation]
  @user.reset_password_token = ""
  @user.save!
  if @user.errors.empty?
    redirect_to new_user_session_url, :notice => "Your password has been changed."
  else
    redirect_to new_user_session_url, :flash => { :error => @user.errors.full_messages  }
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you building a reset password feature yourself? Devise has automatically built in reset password feature under the `recoverable` module. Also, can you post the stack trace or log output here. Thanks.

Comment: I'm not building it myself, I'm just trying to get Devise's to work. Will update the question with the log output.

Comment: Are you sure that you have the proper version of devise?

Comment: I am. `Using devise (3.1.1) `

Comment: If your on RoR 3 you should be on devise 2.x.x

Comment: The devise github page says that "Devise 3.0 works with Rails 3.2 onwards."

Comment: Hmmm, that must be new. I'm sorry I don't really know how to help you then.

Comment: What is PUT change.user? Surely that is not the update password URL

Comment: It is the URL, yeah. Don't know why it's got the `.` in it. The request token one does too and that works fine. I'll update the question with the routes anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I was suffering the same problem with Devise 2.2 / Rails 3.2 / Ruby 2.1. My logs just showed Devise making the SELECT query to find the user and then BEGIN a transaction, then immediately ROLLBACK. I tried updating to Devise 3.0, 3.1 and 3.2. Each time generating fresh devise initialiser and views:

```
rails generate devise:install

rails generate devise:views
```

That was unsuccessful. So I installed the 'byebug' debugger. Then located the devise files with:

```
bundle show devise
```

Edited the password controller:

```
sudo nano /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/devise-3.2.4/app/controllers/devise/passwords_controller.rb
```

Added a debug breakpoint in the *update* method and inspected the errors. I found that it was just a validation on my User model that was causing the error. But because the error was on a specific field, *simple_form* wouldn't display it. In the end, to make debugging easier, I add a line to record the errors in my log:

```
if resource.errors.empty?
  ...
else
  logger.debug "[Devise] #{resource.errors.full_messages}"
  respond_with resource
end
```